# How to create session on client after authenticating with an OpenID Connect Provider

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, openid-connect, openid

OpenID Provider: Okta

Client Library used: [node-openid-client](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client)

Server Technology: Node.js

FrontEnd Technology: React

Problem:

Authentication and retrieval of id_token and access_token was successful. I was able to map the email retrieved from email claim to a user on my server. Now I wish to create a "local" session on my server for the mapped user so that the frontend is aware of a logged in user.

The problem is "When should this local session expire?". I could use the `exp` claim from the token but that is too short for example 15 minutes. My server does support a session touch on every activity so for as long as client is active I am fine but I still feel the the `exp` claim is too short to be used as the expiry for the local session on my server.

If this is not the correct way to create sessions on client then please enlighten me with something useful. I read the [docs on managing sessions in a OIDC flow](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RPLogout) but I don't think this is what I need. This article is on how to keep the session in sync with the one on OpenID Provider.  My problem roots before this even comes up.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally the `exp` claim inside the ID Token is not for you to tie the expiration of an RP session to because as you've already figured out. the ID Token's expiration is kept short. That's because its only use is to communicate Authentication Request results to the RP.

There is no mechanism in the protocol to dictate the RP sessions and so the answer is that it's entirely up to you for how long you wish to establish your RP session for. Same goes for the strategy you'll use to "keep it alive".

Comment: Thanks for confirming this Filip. Looks like every RP has its own way to dictate their sessions and so I guess I shouldn't be worried about having mine.